# C# conditional operator with Entity Framework appears to be evaluating both expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm hoping someone can educate me here. I'm building an Entity Framework query and referencing an object in my where clause that could be null. I'm attempting to use a conditional operator (?:) to check for null but both sides of the conditional operator appear to be getting evaluated and hence, I get a null reference exception. The same conditional operator works if I pull it out of the entity framework context, i.e. the right side doesn't get evaluated and no NRE.

What doesn't work is when I put that into an entity framework query. Apparently, `w.EquipmentTypeInfo.Identity.EntityKey` still gets evaluated even though `EquipmentTypeInfo` is null as verified in debug:

```
var equipment = context.Equipments.Where(d =>
       d.RouteEquipmentInfoType == w.RouteEquipmentInfoType
    && d.EquipmentTypeInfoEntityKey == (w.EquipmentTypeInfo == null ? null : w.EquipmentTypeInfo.Identity.EntityKey)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Can someone please explain to me why the conditional operator doesn't work in the context of an EF query?

What is the best way to handle objects that might be null in an EF where clause?

Comment: What is `w`? It seems to be a class instance, which makes me wonder why `d.RouteEquipmentInfoType == w.RouteEquipmentInfoType` is accepted by EF6.

Comment: w is in fact a class instance and RouteEquipmentInfoType on both d and w is a string so it's comparing a string to a string.

Comment: When `w.EquipmentTypeInfo == null`, in EF6 you should get "Non-static method requires a target" to translate the entire query into SQL. If this is ef-core 6 (if so, please change the tag) it doesn't throw a NRE because the values are evaluated before query translation. So please give more details on the exact content of `w` for cases that succeed and fail.

Answer (score 0):

As Parsa says, it could be Identity (provided that Identity is a reference type and not a struct).  It could also be d if Equipments can contain nulls.

You could simplify this by using the null-conditional expression as well as passing the filter predicate directly to FirstOrDefault rather than using Where:

```
var equipment = context.Equipments.FirstOrDefault(d =>
   d.RouteEquipmentInfoType == w?.RouteEquipmentInfoType && 
   d.EquipmentTypeInfoEntityKey == w?.EquipmentTypeInfo?.Identity?.EntityKey);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can't use the "?." syntax. That's what I tried first but it produces a compile error: An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator. But I've verified that everything is non-null except for EquipmentTypeInfo. I checked the query by replacing the null conditional with 1 just to make sure it was in fact the conditional causing the error and with a 1 the query executes successfully.